# XXXX is not a valid value for the 'yyyy-color' property

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio does a lot to help you make sure that your html/xhtml is valid and well formed. This is nice except for when you are breaking those rules knowing full well what you are doing and why. I really would like to 'turn off' the validation messages that tell me that css 3 named colors are not valid for the version of css it thinks I'm targeting.

How do I get VS to calm down and not warn me about some of this stuff?

Comment: @CJM Thank you; What I want is a way to disable this particular class of error not to disable all unknown properties or invalid values. Humph(:

Comment: The CSS3 color module is still a Working Draft and therefore not really intended to be implemented by browsers or user by authors. I'd be surprised if any authoring tool had any level of support for it yet...

Answer (score 2):

Try Options > Tools > Text Editor > CSS > CSS Specific.

You can uncheck one or more of:

- Detect Errors
- Detect Unknown Properties
- Detect Invalid Values

Comment: **In Visual Studio 2010 SP1:** *Tools* > *Options...* > *Text Editor* > *CSS* > Miscellaneous